# error installing MySQL-python on RHEL 6

Tags: python, gcc, pip, mysql-python, yum

I have tried yum install MYSQL-python, pip install  MySQL-python and easy_install  MySQL-python.

Get this error: `error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1`

```
Cleaning up...
Command /usr/local/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_root/MySQL-python/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-rpOkcR-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_root/MySQL-python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 8, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==1.5.6', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/__init__.py", line 185, in main
    return command.main(cmd_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 161, in main
    text = '\n'.join(complete_log)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 65: ordinal not in range(128)
```

yum install worked and it said: `Package MySQL-python-1.2.3-0.3.c1.1.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version.`

But when i open python and type : import MySQLdb it says `ImportError: No module named mysqldb`

Even tried manually installing gcc via yum install gcc or yum install python-devel...all didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Set your terminal encoding to `UTF-8`, run following in terminal:

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @GerarddeVisser is it okay now?

Answer (score 0):

found the answer: `yum install mysql-devel.x86_64`

Seems like yum install mysql-devel didnt do it. Had to be more specific..

[Install mysql-python return error in CentOs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13044201/install-mysql-python-return-error-in-centos)